# gRPC doesn't work on a raspberry Pi (armv7l)

Tags: raspberry-pi, grpc, grpc-java

**tl:/dr: gRPC stalls the cloud api on a raspberry pi.**

I am led to believe this because Google Firebase works (doesn't use gRPC), but Google Firestore and Google TextToSpeech stalls (both use gRPC), and throws lots of warnings involving NativeLibraryLoader - io_grpc_netty_shaded_netty_tcnative_linux_arm_32

Both APIs (Firestore and TextToSpeech) will authenticate, but when I try to do something real (list documents in Firestore, or download a WAV in TTS) it just... halts.  No errors.  The exact same code runs fine on a laptop, same JRE (OpenJDK 11).

I am seeing this issue on a

- Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
- Debian Buster (10.1)
- Linux ev3dev 4.19.23-ev3dev-3-beta1-rpi2 #1 SMP Sun Mar 3 21:13:28 CST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
- openjdk version "11.0.5" 2019-10-15
- Kotlin 1.3

My testing

1. [Firebase](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-admin/6.10.0) using the Java Admin API: connects, reads, listens for realtime updates.
2. [Firestore](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-firestore) using the Java Admin API: connects (!), but hangs indefinitely on collection read.
3. [TextToSpeech](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-texttospeech) using the Java Admin API: connects (!), but hangs indefinitely on reading the WAV file.

[Log file demonstrating the warnings](https://gist.github.com/salamanders/3359f6a6b2c269c431825e103df6c76f)

Workaround attempted:

- Upgraded from Java 8 to OpenJDK 11
- manually including io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static

Reasons why this is a high severity:

1. It doesn't just error out with a "not supported on your platform", it stalls forever. This makes a dev run around trying to debug lots of factors.
2. Some Google Cloud products use gRPC, some don't.  So a hobbyist has to do research for what might break.
3. rPIs are very popular for prototyping IoT, and for enthusiasts in general.

Comment: what do you mean tried jdk11? it sounds like it didn't work, what's the error?

Comment: That's the tricky thing - there is no error I can point at.  The app just... stops!  Even with debug turned on, it tosses out a bunch of debug warnings, but when I get to calling an actual Cloud API call (and I think this is where gRPC comes in) it just hangs.